# copying matrixes in c

Tags: c, matrix, copy, malloc

So I ve got this:
char table1[10^length][length];
char table2[10^length][length];

And compiler doesn't let me dot this:
table1=table2;

my code is supposed to take a string with wild caracters (only ?)

and give all the possible strings in the output (well it is a part of a bigger project but lets say print them in terminal - if I do this I can handle the rest)

Here is the full code:

```
int ** wildReplacement(char *wildAM,int length)
{
    length=7;
    char * temp;
    strcpy(wildAM,"123?23");
    //getchar();
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int l=0;
    int limit=0;
    int wildCharsNum;
    char *nlptr= NULL;

    char table1[10^length][length];
    char table2[10^length][length];


    wildCharsNum=charOccurenciesInStr(wildAM,'?');
    strcpy(temp,wildAM);
    strcpy(table1[0],wildAM);

    printf("\n!!WildChars In wildAM:%d",wildCharsNum);


    while(k<wildCharsNum)
    {
        l=0;
        while(l<=limit)
        {
            strcpy(temp,table1[l]);
            i=0;
            nlptr = strchr(temp, '?');//ka8e fora vriskei to epomeno ?
            if (nlptr) 
            {
                for(j=1;j<10;j++)
                {
                    *nlptr = myItoc(j);//antikatastasi tou ? me digits sto temp
                    strcpy(table2[i],temp);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            l++;
        }
        table1=table2;
        limit=i;
    k++;
    }

    printf("\nWild Numbers out:");
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s",table1[i]);
    }

}
```

Should I malloc like:

```
char ** table1
char ** table2

table1=malloc(sizeof(char)*10^length*lenght)
table2=malloc(sizeof(char)*10^length*lenght)
```

How would the programm know when each record ends

Then what would this mean:
table1[1] ? probably nothing...

Thanks in advance

Comment: `^` does not mean exponentiation, means bitwise xor.

Comment: Why is `length` is passed in as an argument then immediately set to 7?

Comment: Thank u K-ballo, you are right I changed it to pow() and everything works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `malloc` a two dimensional array you can't construct something that's identical to what the compiler would make for an array declaration.  `char a[100][50]` is a contiguous blob of memory that's 5000 `char`.  When you subscript it the compiler is able to do the row/column math because it knew the size at compile time.  When you `malloc` an equivalent two-dimensional array you have to provide a row array that indexes the rows.  This is how you answer your question "how would the program know when each record ends":

```
char **b;
int i;
int rows = 100;
int cols = 50;
/* using sizeof(*b) is a good habit because there's only */
/* one place where you have to change type information */
b = malloc(rows * sizeof(*b));
/* now create a bunch of rows */
for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    b[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(**b));
}
```

Notice that this takes more memory than the declared array because of the `rows` indexing array.

As an optimization you can avoid the repeated `malloc` in the loop and parcel out memory from a single large allocation of `rows * cols * sizeof(**b)`.

Take care you write a matching function to `free` your array.

Comment: Allocating a 2-d array in a flat manner if perfectly well possible in C with `malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(T))`. That solution preserves locality of reference and simplifies deallocation/error checking.

Comment: Larsmans, how do you propose to dereference it?  I got the impression the question was about adapting fixed arrays to dynamic arrays.  If you want to preserve the syntax `table[y][x]` you need something like I describe.

Comment: You can use a pointer to array of `char` instead of just to `char`, something like `char (*b)[50]; b = malloc(rows * sizeof(*b));`, to allocate an array of arrays instead... then you don't need an array of pointers.

Comment: i think Ben's code should be what I was asking but..
this babe did the trick too :D 
memcpy(table1,table2,sizeof(char)*(int)(pow(10,(k+1)))*(length+1));

had to alter the code though, I ll post the answer when the system lets me